# SharePoint Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070005

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint, wss-3.0, deployment

Oh SharePoint...

I've built a custom event receiver that just checks for some fields from the list, and changes some of them as needed.

Still, it's throwing this exception:

Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070005
ERROR: Failed invoking job id {C67EFFCB-607A-4B6A-8C90-60F615FD1878}

Seen that it might be a security issue, and, in another stackoverflow topic I've seen that it may even be because im using the following code:

```
  SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteId))
                {
                    this.DisableEventFiring();
                  // Logic code.
                  // ...
                }
             });
```

But removing it will need a recompile, and redeploy. Thought it would be better asking to have sure first.

In the production environment, we have two servers, one for the sites, and one for the database. Active directory is also implemented and fully functional. And for what I've checked, all accounts have the "create subsite" permission on Central Administration, as seen in another topic.

So any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved.

After writing logs and exceptions to txt files, and being mislead by the sharepoint log, What was really happening was that a column name was wrong in my code. Since this is a very specific customization, it had some column names literally wrote to the code. One of them had '_' around it, like `_Column_` IN THE LIST, IN SHAREPOINT.

But as it goes to SQL, it didn't have the '_'s.

Looking back it appears that someone created the list and then renamed it.  So when you create a list, it registers in SQL the FIRST name of the column. If you change it, it wont be changed on SQL, it will be changed in the list, in SharePoint, but the column name in SQL will still have its original name...

If you already knew that congrats, because that was such a finding for me...

Comment: Did you change InternalName of column ?
Because you CAN change display name if you wish.

Comment: Well I'd rather dont mess with that. They changed the display name, the internal stills the same... and as it goes to SQL, it's even more messed up. So, I'll just rebuild the EventReceiver, and leave that alone. Thanks for the tipo though.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying to use

```
this.DisableEventFiring();
try
{
  using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteId, properties.Site.SystemAccount.UserToken) {

  }
}
finally
{
this.EnableEventFiring();
}
```

Ofcourse you can't without RunWithElevatedPrivileges if you want to modify some files on filesystem there, but otherwise it may help.